# Suppress lines with more than 3 words in UpperCase in Perl - RegExp

Tags: regex, perl

I need to create a Perl script in order to suppress all lines of more than 3 words in UpperCase (each word is separated by a space).

For now, I have delete all sentences in UpperCase like that:

```
  while(my $text = <IN>)
  {
    $text =~ s/(^[A-Z \d\W]+$)\n//g;
  }
```

Comment: `next if @{[ $text =~ /\b[A-Z]+\b/g ]} >3;` replace + with `{2,}` if you don't want to count single letter words.

Answer (score 3):

Utilize [perlfaq4 - How can I count the number of occurrences of a substring within a string?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string%3f) to count the number of matches of your pattern.

Then apply a filter:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    my $uc_words = () = /\b[A-Z]{2,}\b/g;
    print if $uc_words < 3;

}
__DATA__
FIRST lower SECOND
FIRST lower SECOND and THIRD and end
FIRST and SECOND and just an I, is that enough?
Filter me because of FIRST, SECOND, THIRD, and FOURTH.
Just First Letter Capitalized Is Cool, Right?
```

Outputs:

```
FIRST lower SECOND
FIRST and SECOND and just an I, is that enough?
Just First Letter Capitalized Is Cool, Right?
```

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern

```
^(?=(.*\b[A-Z]+\b){3}).*(\n|$)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/137)

```
^               # Start of string/line
(?=             # Look-Ahead
  (             # Capturing Group (1)
    .           # Any character except line break
    *           # (zero or more)(greedy)
    \b          # <word boundary>
    [A-Z]       # Character Class [A-Z]
    +           # (one or more)(greedy)
    \b          # <word boundary>
  )             # End of Capturing Group (1)
  {3}           # (repeated {3} times)
)               # End of Look-Ahead
.               # Any character except line break
*               # (zero or more)(greedy)
(               # Capturing Group (2)
  \n            # <new line>
  |             # OR
  $             # End of string/line
)               # End of Capturing Group (2)
```

Comment: Why not use some Perl code instead of trying to squeeze an entire program into a regular expression? In any case it's wrong, because it checks only whether a string has *at least three* all-capitals words.

Comment: I provided a regex example to to match what the OP is asking for, the OP is free to use it however he/she wants whether to load an entire file or loop through each line is up to him/her. but to your comment about at least three, you're right, I missed it, it is so easy to modify my pattern to `^(?=(.*\b[A-Z]+\b){4}).*(\n|$)`